# Passed Segue variable keeps clearing after load

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

So I have been working on learning swift and I have come across and issue that has had me stuck for awhile. I am passing the data from the first controller to the second controller using the seques.

When I print the variable onLoad it prints out the correct values passed, however after I execute another function (click on a red button) it doesn't print out the passed values but instead blank values.

```
var Level = 0;
var userId: String = "";
var clanId: String = "";
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print(userId); //prints 97
    print(clanId); //prins 2
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func redButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
     print(userId); //prints ""
    print(clanId); //prins ""
}
```

As you can see on in the code it seems to be something pretty simple but obviously I am missing how this works as after the onload the variables contain nothing in them.

Thanks everyone for the help!

------------------EDIT----------------------

Changed the values userId: String = "test"
Changed the values clanId: String = "test"

It now prints out in onload function

```
 print(userId)
 print(clanId)

 results:
 97
 2
 test
 test
```

----------------ADDITION-----------

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dashboard", sender: self);
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "dashboard")
        {
            let dutydash:dashboardController  = segue.destinationViewController as! dashboardController;
            dutydash.userId = self.userId;
           dutydash.clanId = self.clanId;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not initializating userId and clanId? (`var userId: String! var clanId: String! `) They might be getting reset to their original values when the button is clicked?

Comment: After making those changes I received this:

97
2
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Then if I added a ? instead of ! I get the output 92, 2, nil, nil

Comment: Please share some code from the first controller, when and how you segue to destination

Comment: @Aamir I have added it to the main question

Comment: You're setting userID and companyID in that code, not clanID

Comment: @sschale whoops. I fixed that part, that was a mistype. I copied and pasted this tim.

Comment: What do you see if you override viewDidAppear and print the two variables there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a working example, ensure your data is being set in `prepareForSegue`.

```
class prevClass: UIViewController{

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "nextView" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NextView
            destinationVC.userId = "77789";
            destinationVC.clanId = "Awesome Clan"

        }
    }
    @IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextView", sender: self)

    }
}

class NextView: UIViewController {

    var userId: String!
    var clanId: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    @IBAction func redButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(userId);
        print(clanId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple suggestions:

- Change your initial setting of `userId` and `clanId` to something else instead of `""`, like `"test"` to see if that's a problem
- In Swift, you don't need `;` at the end of each line
- All variables should be camel case (starting with lowercase), so change `Level` to `level`

Comment: I changed it to test and now I get the print out (during the onload function)

97
2
test
test


Then when I click other functions I get  test

Comment: Ok, so what's happening is they're getting assigned again because of the lifecycle of the VC. As @kye mentioned, you can just change them to `var userId: String!` if you're sure they'll be set by the other VC, or you'll crash.

Comment: I commented on his stamen above. It throws an error stating it found a nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: Is there anything else in your code that touches those variables?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can think is that you are maybe running two or more instances of the view controller at the same time. Print "self" at viewdidload and inside the button action and check if both are equal.